# How to "cherry-pick" elements, re-positioning them within the DOM?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have a video element that is dynamically added to the DOM by an external Javascript library after view initialization. What I wish to do is remove it from its original parent and append it as a child node of another. Is there an intended way to do this in Angular 2, using Renderer for example? I already have a reference to the video element from a callback function of the external library.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now using the Renderer class's 'projectNodes' method to move elements within the DOM. This can be used in place of 'appendChild'. The only slight hassle is the need to pass an array to this method even if just 1 node needs to be manipulated.